# SQL CASE Statement for no data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, case

I have a table that has process engines 1,2,3,4,5,6 with a running status. When one of the engines is down the record gets deleted from the table. Using a case statement I can display the first engine that is down but how do I go about displaying the engines if 2 or more engines are down. For e.g. how do I make this query display PE 2 IS DOWN and PE 4 is DOWN if both the engines are down. Right now it displays only the first engine in the list that is down .

```
    SELECT CASE
WHEN (SELECT COUNT(PE_ID) FROM CWVMINFO WHERE PE_ID = 1) = 0 THEN 'PE 1 IS DOWN'
WHEN (SELECT COUNT(PE_ID) FROM CWVMINFO WHERE PE_ID = 2) = 0 THEN 'PE 2 IS DOWN'
WHEN (SELECT COUNT(PE_ID) FROM CWVMINFO WHERE PE_ID = 3) = 0 THEN 'PE 3 IS DOWN'
WHEN (SELECT COUNT(PE_ID) FROM CWVMINFO WHERE PE_ID = 4) = 0 THEN 'PE 4 IS DOWN'
WHEN (SELECT COUNT(PE_ID) FROM CWVMINFO WHERE PE_ID = 5) = 0 THEN 'PE 5 IS DOWN'
WHEN (SELECT COUNT(PE_ID) FROM CWVMINFO WHERE PE_ID = 6) = 0 THEN 'PE 6 IS DOWN'
ELSE 'ALL PROCESS ENGINES ARE UP AND RUNNING'
END "STATUS"
from dual;
```

Comment: what database are you using?  a better targeted script can be made depending on the database.

Comment: @ps2goat `dual` is usually oracle

Comment: I'm using ORACLE 11.2.0

Comment: @Lashane, thanks, I never got into using Oracle at that level.  I thought he just named his table that.

Comment: The best place to start would be to create a table that contains a list of your process engines. Writing a query to determine their status becomes much simpler if you have an authoritative list to start with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of case, using `union all` for the two different cases, all good versus some not running. Sub query factoring to reduce repeated code.

```
with engines as (select level as engine_number 
    from dual 
    connect by level <= 6)
, down_engines as (select engine_number
    from engines
    where engine_number not in (select pe_id from cwvminfo))
select to_char(engine_number) || ' IS DOWN'
from down_engines 
union all
select 'all engines are running'
from dual
where not exists (select null from down_engines)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite this using a single query and conditional aggregation:

```
select coalesce(case when sum(case when pe_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
                     then 'PE 1 IS DOWN; '
                end) ||
               (case when sum(case when pe_id = 1 then 2 else 0 end) = 0
                     then 'PE 2 IS DOWN; '
                end) ||
               (case when sum(case when pe_id = 1 then 3 else 0 end) = 0
                     then 'PE 3 IS DOWN; '
                end) ||
               (case when sum(case when pe_id = 1 then 4 else 0 end) = 0
                     then 'PE 4 IS DOWN; '
                end) ||
               (case when sum(case when pe_id = 1 then 5 else 0 end) = 0
                     then 'PE 5 IS DOWN; '
                end) ||
               (case when sum(case when pe_id = 1 then 6 else 0 end) = 0
                     then 'PE 6 IS DOWN; '
                end), 'ALL PROCESS ENGINES ARE UP AND RUNNING') as status
from CWVMINFO;
```

Or, alternatively, if you don't have to have a single row, you might do:

```
select ids.id,
       (case when count(c.pe_id) = 0 then "DOWN' else 'UP' end) as status
from (select 1 as id from dual union all select 2 from dual union all select 3 from dual union all
      select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 from dual
     ) ids left join
     CWVMINFO c
     on c.pe_id = ids.id
group by ids.id
order by ids.id;
```

This would make it more obvious that everything is being checked.

Comment: Thank you so much for this Gordon!

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiple `CASE` expressions to return status for each:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(PE_ID) FROM CWVMINFO WHERE PE_ID = 1) = 0 THEN 'PE 1 IS DOWN' END AS PE_1
      ,CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(PE_ID) FROM CWVMINFO WHERE PE_ID = 2) = 0 THEN 'PE 2 IS DOWN' END AS PE_2
      ,CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(PE_ID) FROM CWVMINFO WHERE PE_ID = 3) = 0 THEN 'PE 3 IS DOWN' END AS PE_3
      ,CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(PE_ID) FROM CWVMINFO WHERE PE_ID = 4) = 0 THEN 'PE 4 IS DOWN' END AS PE_4
      ,CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(PE_ID) FROM CWVMINFO WHERE PE_ID = 5) = 0 THEN 'PE 5 IS DOWN' END AS PE_5
      ,CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(PE_ID) FROM CWVMINFO WHERE PE_ID = 6) = 0 THEN 'PE 6 IS DOWN' END AS PE_6
       from dual)
SELECT *,CASE WHEN COALESCE(PE_1,PE_2,PE_3,PE_4,PE_5,PE_6) IS NULL THEN 'ALL PROCESS ENGINES ARE UP AND RUNNING' END "STATUS"
FROM cte
```

Comment: I don't think your alternate query will work ... there won't be any rows with that particular value of `PE_ID`.

Comment: FYI ... you'll need `FROM dual` in your CTE.

Comment: Thank you so much Hart! Getting a FROM keyword cannot be found error for some reason but I get the basic idea with how these types of queries can be handled.

Comment: @ram81012 Maybe the `from dual` isn't actually necessary? Sadly I can't test it out to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a stored procedure with if condition for each of the case you have here.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following. It's a bit kludgy but I think it might work.

```
WITH p1 AS (
    SELECT LEVEL AS pe_id
      FROM dual
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6
)
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN all_ind = 0 THEN 'ALL PROCESS ENGINES ARE UP AND RUNNING'
  WHEN process_cnt = 0 THEN 'PE ' || pe_id || ' IS DOWN' END AS status
  FROM (
    SELECT pe_id, process_cnt
         , SUM(DECODE(process_cnt, 0, 1, 0)) OVER ( ) AS all_ind
      FROM (
        SELECT p1.pe_id, COUNT(c1.pe_id) AS process_cnt
          FROM p1 LEFT JOIN cwvminfo c1
            ON p1.pe_id = c1.pe_id
         GROUP BY p1.pe_id
    )
)
```

[Please see SQL Fiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2f97c3/1)

Comment: Thank you so much David! The query pulls a null in the result set for some reason but I can handle just the null and get the rest of the data.

Comment: It will pull a `NULL`. I would have done something to filter it out but I didn't want to get too deep with the subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COALESCE` and `LISTAGG`:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(
         LISTAGG('PE ' || pe_id || ' IS DOWN', ' and ')
           WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY pe_id),
         'ALL PROCESS ENGINES ARE UP AND RUNNING'
       ) AS status
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT pe_id
  FROM   CWVMINFO
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE CWVMINFO (pe_id NUMBER);
```

Outputs:

> | STATUS |
> | --- |
> | ALL PROCESS ENGINES ARE UP AND RUNNING |

If you:

```sql
INSERT INTO CWVMINFO (pe_id) VALUES (1);
```

Then it outputs:

> | STATUS |
> | --- |
> | PE 1 IS DOWN |

Then, if you:

```sql
INSERT INTO CWVMINFO (pe_id) VALUES (3);
```

Then it outputs:

> | STATUS |
> | --- |
> | PE 1 IS DOWN and PE 3 IS DOWN |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d00c0fcaa8bcd5be1aaa2852193e708e)*