# Oracle case statement not returning values for no row results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple case statement as follows:

```
  select 
  case WHEN upper(VALUE) is null then 'A_VALUE_ANYWAY' end test 
FROM 
  V$SYSTEM_PARAMETER 
WHERE 
  UPPER(VALUE)= 'NO_VALUE_IS_HERE'
```

This code is designed to return 'A_VALUE_ANYWAY' because there is no output from the SQL.

However, it does not return anything at all.

Essentially, what I would like is a value being forced to return from the case statement instead of just no rows.

Am I able to do that with the case statement? Is there some form of no data found handler I should be using instead?

I have examined this similar question but this is very complex and does not seem possible with this more simple statement

[SQL CASE Statement for no data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28442921/sql-case-statement-for-no-data)

Also, this, which uses a union to get a value from dual:

[Select Case, when no data return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707937/select-case-when-no-data-return)

Which seems like a "Fudge" I feel like there must be some designed way to handle no data being found in a case statement.

Comment: Just use `... NVL2(min(upper (value)).. `

Comment: Like this? select 
  case WHEN NVL2(
    min(
      upper(value)
    ) is null then 'A_VALUE_ANYWAY' end test 
    FROM 
      V$SYSTEM_PARAMETER 
    WHERE 
      NVL2(
        min(
          upper(value)
        )= 'NO_VALUE_IS_HERE'

Comment: NVL2 is a syntactic sugar for case. Don't change your original `where` clause, just use min or max for `upper(value) ` in case expression

Comment: That's a `case` _expression_, not statement.

Comment: No, there is no built-in way to return a row if a select returns no rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking is: "if my query returns no rows, I want to see a value". That cannot be solved with a case expression. A case expression transforms the results of your query. If there are no results, nothing can be transformed. Instead you could could modify your query and union it with another select from dual that returns a string if the query itself returns no results. That way either part of the `UNION ALL` will return something.

```
SELECT 
  VALUE
FROM 
  V$SYSTEM_PARAMETER 
WHERE 
  UPPER(VALUE)= 'NO_VALUE_IS_HERE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A_VALUE_ANYWAY' 
  FROM  
    DUAL 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                     FROM 
                       V$SYSTEM_PARAMETER 
                    WHERE UPPER(VALUE)= 'NO_VALUE_IS_HERE'
```

This is the same technique as in the [SQL Case statement for no data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28442921/sql-case-statement-for-no-data) question.

Comment: A case expression returns a value, and can be used in regular DML. A case statement is a PL/SQL construction used for conditional execution of code.

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can use the `FETCH` syntax so that you do not have to query the table multiple times:

```sql
SELECT value
FROM   (
  SELECT value,
         1 AS priority
  FROM   V$SYSTEM_PARAMETER 
  WHERE  UPPER(VALUE)= 'NO_VALUE_IS_HERE'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A_VALUE_ANYWAY',
         2
  FROM   DUAL
  ORDER BY priority
  FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8136ce7f5197bc4c731a772d453e2e57)*